# Expected type not matching Actual Type

Tags: haskell

Let's say for sake of argument that I have the two functions defined below, along with the `Var` type:

```
  data Var = String | Int

   Increment :: Int -> Int 
   Increment a = (a +1)

   Compute :: Var -> Maybe Int
    Compute b = case b of 
         Int -> Just(Increment b)
         String -> Nothing
```

Even though I'm checking that b is of type `Int` before calling `increment` on it, I'm getting an error stating that the Expected type Int is not matched by the Actual type Var.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Names starting with an uppercase letter are reserved for data types or data constructors. The name of an ordinary function may not start with an uppercase letter. Please always always include the full text of your error message in the question. Also mind the indentation. Top function definitions to start in leftmost column.

Comment: You are not in fact "checking that b is of type Int" - you're checking that b, which by your type signature must be of type Var, has the value Int, which you have defined as one of the two data constructors of the Var type. You probably want `type Var = Either Int String` (or make your own type which is equivalent) so you can pattern match while also extracting the underlying value. If you look up the `Either` type and how it is used you should get a good idea of what to do.

Comment: You probably wanted something like: `data Var = MyVarString String | MyVarInt Int  deriving  (Eq, Show)`  - your String enum-like constructor is hiding the built-in String data type.

Comment: what you wrote is not Haskell. in particular, Haskell's `case` is not Common Lisp's `typecase`. Haskell variables can't have different types. instead they refer to values, and a value has only one type.  (sans parametric polymorphism)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems is that the definition:

```
data Var = String | Int
```

gets parsed by Haskell exactly like:

```
data Language = English | Spanish | French | Russian
```

because the two constructors have no arguments. So `Var` is essentially an enumerative type, with just 2 possible values named String and Int which happen to hide their namesake Haskell built-in data types..

**Testing under the `ghci` interpreter:**

```
 λ> 
 λ> data Var = String | Int deriving (Eq, Show)
 λ> 
 λ> v = String
 λ> 
 λ> :type v
 v :: Var
 λ> 
 λ> v
 String
 λ>
```

You probably wanted something like:

```
data Var = MyVarString String | MyVarInt Int  deriving  (Eq, Show)
```

where `String` is the built-in data type, and `MyVarString` is your own private local constructor.

```
 λ> 
 λ> data Var = MyVarString String | MyVarInt Int  deriving  (Eq, Show)
 λ> 
 λ> v = MyVarString "abc"
 λ> 
 λ> v
 MyVarString "abc"
 λ> 
 λ> :type v
 v :: Var
 λ>
```

Also, your local functions need to be slightly reformatted:

```
-- leftmost-indented, name starting with lowercase letter:
increment :: Int -> Int 
increment a = (a +1)

-- leftmost-indented, name starting with lowercase letter:
compute :: Var -> Maybe Int
compute b = case b of 
         MyVarInt v      ->  Just (increment v)
         MyVarString st  ->  Nothing
```

Sample test program:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Hello impure world !"
    let  v1 = MyVarInt 42
         mi = compute v1
    putStrLn ("compute v1 : " ++ (show mi))
```

**Test program output:**

```
Hello impure world !
compute v1 : Just 43
```

Comment: You're the best man, thanks for the explanation I knew I was missing something just didn't know what this explanation clarified everything!!

Comment: Thanks Ted sorry I thought upvoting was the same as accepting !